# Filter inbound request http

Tags: iis-6, filtering

I have some website on IIS6 on Windows 2003. I want to allow for one website only http connection from some IP addresses.
Is it possible to do so by acting on the configuration of IIS?
Thanks

Oronzo

Answer (score 1):

So you want to grant or deny access to a website based on the IP address of the user?

Here is a Microsoft Technet set of articles that tell you how to restrict access on IIS 6.

[Securing Sites with IP Address Restrictions (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/128d26dd-decb-42f9-8efb-30724d1a2f29.mspx?mfr=true)
It gives instructions for securing it for a single IP, a domain and an ip subnet.